# Common Lisp: deleting unreachable code

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, declare

This is an easy one.

```
(let ((x))
(if (typep x 'null) "a" "b"))
```

generate a warning about unreachable code deletion. Presumably the compiler was smart enough to figure that it is only executed once and the type will always be null. I wouldn't normally write that code, but in this case I just don't want the code deletion notice in my output. How can I shut SBCL up about that particular warning? As a note, I also haven't been able to find the right syntax to tell sbcl to set safety to 0 so that I can overflow an integer (educationally)... Perhaps related?

Thanks,
   Conrad

Comment: You've already tried `(declare (optimize (safety 0)))` for the allowing-overflow part of your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap whatever compiles the code in a handler-bind with a handler for `sb-ext:compiler-note` that's handled with `muffle-warning`. See also http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Controlling-Verbosity

SBCL has modular arithmetic, so you can get very fast arithmetic by declaring variable types and wrapping the operations in `(logand mask (+ x y))`, where the mask is `#xFFFF` or `#xFFFFFFFF` or whatever. See also http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Modular-arithmetic